# Is there a way to tell when NTP has updated the time

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

In Ubuntu, is there a way to tell when the system time has been updated by NTP? My use case is that I have an embedded system that may or may not be connected to the internet. If it's not, and then it gets connected and NTP updates the time, I want to know that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are manually synching the clock(i.e. ntpd -gq), and you need to know when NTP is finished synching, you may want to look into [ntp-wait](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntp-wait). This tool will wait until ntp is in a synchronized state.

But, if you are wanting to know each time your server's clock is updated, which is what NTP does automatically at given intervals, you can monitor the loopstats file. The last entry will be the last update to the server's clock. See [this](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/monopt.html) for explanation of loopstats entry.

Also, `ntpdc` will give you a server's offset from the time source in milliseconds as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We solved this a different way but this is very good into to have.